# I can't see orders in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, error, currency

I can't see the magento orders. This error appears:

> a:5:{i:0;s:28:"Currency '39.7000' not found";i:1;s:4910:"#0
>   /home/XX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(614)

I checked the `sales_flat_order` table and I think that it's all ok. I don't know if there is another related table.

Comment: What locale and currency are you using ?

Comment: I am using EUR and ES

Answer (score 1):

Check the column's values `base_currency_code` and `order_currency_code` for all your orders. I suppose, one of them contains the wrong value. They should contain currency codes and nothing else (e.g. numbers).

[image]

In addition, check all the columns for the `currency` attribute value:

[image]

May be the other column is specified. You should specify exactly the one that contains currency code.

Comment: I have just checked the order list has the column G.T. (Purchased) with the value of **28.7400** instead of **28,74€**.

Comment: @guest you should check the columns `base_curency_code` and `order_curency_code`, but not `GT purchased`. These columns shouldn't contain any numbers, only currency codes.